# How to play audio of a casted tab in Chrome browser on the casted device?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, screencasts, google-meet

--- TLDR
Audio of a casted tab in Chrome browser NOT playing on the casted device but on original machine's speaker. How to switch speaker to casted device?

--- In details

I casted a google-meet call using Chrome browser tab `Cast...`; I chose device is my smart tv in the same wifi network at home.

I can cast the content, but the audio still played on my laptop, NOT the tv.

How can I get the audio played on the tv instead?

[image]

Comment: Add more details. How are you connection you computor to your TV? Are you using an external Chromecast or your smart TV include a built-in way to do the connection? Search [su] add what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: It's a builtin way in the smart tv. Sometimes it get audio played from the tv, the other time it plays on laptop.